# What is the Purpose of Checking lt(fpm, ptr) in Buffer.sol?

Tags: solidity, yul

Recently I checking Buffer.sol smart contract and I found this Code

Link = https://github.com/ensdomains/buffer/blob/master/contracts/Buffer.sol

```
function init(buffer memory buf, uint capacity) internal pure returns(buffer memory) {
    if (capacity % 32 != 0) {
        capacity += 32 - (capacity % 32);
    }
    // Allocate space for the buffer data
    buf.capacity = capacity;
    assembly {
        let ptr := mload(0x40)
        mstore(buf, ptr)
        mstore(ptr, 0)
        let fpm := add(32, add(ptr, capacity))
        if lt(fpm, ptr) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
        mstore(0x40, fpm)
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Here the Code is correct but in many web3 contract I found that

```
 if lt(fpm, ptr) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
```

This Check in missing in many web3 contracts so I want to know what is the purpose of this check while Initializes a buffer with an initial capacity ( Init() function )

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It's just an overflow check.

When calculating `let fpm := add(32, add(ptr, capacity))`, it's possible that `32+prt+capacity` ends up greater than `2**256`; this overflow doesn't raise errors since we are inside a assembly block. Checking that `fpm > ptr` is sufficient to prevent that.